# How to link page using href in PHP MVC

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I want to know, how to get linkup page in PHP MVC.
 
This is my link page, but it's not working.
It's Shows Nothing on webpage.
In This href Link I add Controller/Model/View page link, I am Stuck Overit How TO Solve this, Please Help!
  My Link id is wrong...

```
     <a href='../../Database/databaseConnection.php/Model/Model.php/Controller/Controller.php?Controller=Show_data&action=UserCreationView.php'></a>
```

Comment: Next time please let ppl know what kind of framework you are using as routing depends on individual framework, not on MVC design pattern

Comment: i am not using any kind of php framework

Comment: this is my full href link friend, but it's not work

Comment: <a href='../../Database/databaseConnection.php/Model/Model.php/Controller/Controller.php?Controller=Show_data&action=UserCreationView.php'><img src="../../public/images/ModuleImages/Security.gif" style="height: 130px; width: 150px;"/></a>

Comment: i am stuck on this, i can't open my UserCreationView Page

Comment: to debug, display your image separately see if that one shows up. In the link display text instead of image, see if the link shows up and works. Also your link looks beyond weird: 2 steps back, then access Database folder then database connection script then specify model and controller files, then specify controller and action I assume class names? not sure what you are building this on and dont know the context, but if it is possible jump  to a propper framework

Comment: ok friend thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Ofc it won't show anything.  syntax looks like this:

```
<a href="{your link}">{your visible part}</a>
```

In this case your visible part is missing